# Word Ribbon VBA stops working when copied to Startup Folder

Tags: vba, ms-office, ribbon

I have developed a small Ribbon for our company, which works fine when launched from it's dotm file - but I have problemswhen I try to store it in the Startup folder.
I have stored it as a dotm file and copied it to the startup folder. The ribbons are perfectly visible when launching word, but every click on a menu item causes a runtime error 5941 :(

the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" onLoad="RibbonControl.Onload">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab id="Best" label="My Tools">
        <group id="FBCATI" visible="true" label="Fragebogen"> 
        <dropDown id="FBC1" label="CATI"
                getItemCount="RibbonControl.GetItemCount"
                  getItemLabel="RibbonControl.GetItemLabel"
            getSelectedItemIndex="RibbonControl.GetSelectedItemIndex"
                  onAction="RibbonControl.MyCatiMacro" 
        />
        <dropDown id="FBW1" label="WEB"
                getItemCount="RibbonControl.GetItemCount"
                  getItemLabel="RibbonControl.GetItemLabel"
            getSelectedItemIndex="RibbonControl.GetSelectedItemIndex"
                  onAction="RibbonControl.MyWebMacro" 
        />
      </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

some code behind.

```
Sub Onload(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
  'Creates a ribbon instance for use in this project
  Set myRibbon = ribbon
End Sub

'Callback for DropDown GetItemCount
Sub GetItemCount(ByVal control As IRibbonControl, ByRef count)
  'Tell the ribbon to show 4 items in the dropdown
  count = 6
End Sub
```

Comment: Is it possible your trust settings aren't allowing this template to load macros?  You could add the startup folder to trusted locations to test.

Comment: Startup is in the list of thrustworthy location, also I have activated all VBA code... :/

Comment: Ok, I investigated deeper and it DOES load the VBA code, but fails to find some template...which causes the error. I have added the template to the file, so I am at a loss....

Comment: maybe include the code that is looking for the template in your question?

Comment: In fact, the needes formatting styles are never loaded from the file - I am opening a new thread...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242041/deploy-dotm-file-with-format-styles

Comment: Not sure you will get "formatting" styles from template in the startup folder. You might need to use a standard (not loaded from the startup folder) template to get the styling.

Answer (score 1):

Put your file under %appdata%\Microsoft\Templates\
And create another .dotm file which should be under StartUp folder and which would attach your file with ribbon.