# Deploy Dotm File with format styles?

Tags: vba, add-in, ms-word

I have developed a small VBA macro for Word 2007 / 2010 which uses some format styles (I am not sure that is the best translation, in my german version it is called Formatvorlagen. I mean the styles which are applied to text, like headers).

The macro is deployed to the STARTUP Folder and essentially works - but the format styles are NOT loaded - so the macro cannot find them.

So my question is: how can I deploy format styles to Word? I could overwrite normal.dot, but that is a crappy solution.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably an easier way that I cannot think of at the moment, but you could try the following:

Export the styles you want by clicking the **Change Styles** button on the *Home* tab, selecting **Style Set** and **Save as Style Set**.

The command will save the currently selected style set as a dotx file. The default location is `C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\QuickStyles` - if you copy the file to a new computer and put it in the same directory for the user, you can then load the style set with the **Change Styles** button or in code:

```
ActiveDocument.ApplyQuickStyleSet2 "XXX"
```

where `XXX` is the name of the style as seen under the **Change Styles** button (the same as the styles filename without the dotx extension).